# Jquery plugin not recognize my parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following jquery plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.Table = function (options) {
        var options = $.fn.extend({
            Init: function () { },
            aColumns: []
        }, options);    
        $.each(aColumns, function (i, column) {
            alert(column);
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and it's call:

```
$(this).Table({ aColumns: ['1','2','3'] });
```

i'm getting an error that aColumns is not defined
i'm new to jquery plugin and need some help
thank you

Comment: Is that `dataTables` plugin you are talking about?

Comment: hi, i'm trying to create a table, and i'm familiar with datatables. but i want to learn and do it by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are running loop on aColumns, you need to specify it as options.aColumns because this is now an attribute of options object. You need to access any attribute you pass as option with the parent object which is in your case the options object.

https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#accepting-options

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.Table = function (options) {

    var options = $.fn.extend({
        Init: function () { },
        aColumns: []
    }, options);

    $.each(options.aColumns, function (i, column) {
        alert(column);
    });
    return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```